# Node JS and Java pbkdf2 have different results

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, pbkdf2

I have a node JS encryption that i am trying to translate to Java. But they have different results.

Node

```
const salt = 'randomsalt'
const crypt = pass => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   crypto.pbkdf2(pass, salt, 1000, 256, 'sha1', (err, key) => {
   if (err) reject(err)
    resolve(key)
  })
})
```

Java

```
  private val salt = "randomsalt"
  val keyLength:Int = 256
  val iterationCount:Int = 1000
  private fun generateKey( pass: String): SecretKey? {
    return try {
        val factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1")
        println("pass => $pass")
        println("salt => ${salt.toByteArray()}")
        val spec: KeySpec = PBEKeySpec(pass.toCharArray(), salt.toByteArray(), iterationCount, keyLength)
        SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).encoded, "AES")
    } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
        null
    } catch (e: InvalidKeySpecException) {
        null
    }
}
```

Output:

JS

```
    const password = "password"
    const derivedKey = await crypt(password)
    console.log('derivedKey =>',  derivedKey.toString('base64')) //uYYJrIrFuAb42kCCOPjqAAE5b2XiECBcKWImxWWLvZ8TUT03ZxhJIs9o285jzAsxjEbyefQQSk6I01ZJOm0XveV3BUEAuhYnJRvyesSE7yrti+Lir8mQiRLiFgVfphs590xwuxqD7NhKohow7Vlw0AkdUXVoIFBOHs3VVaTz3cDthmZ8EhoGumU4XZBtiM01Z0e9MthlqOl4Ri0OSWr3SvqW8Yyz/LQvU0SP9EudRCE4MqbHy8vP06NzBFf7BCpHD7oqo61e1xaKmFjfJQgtK8KcLkjLthsDltbXN2PvmCc3z9L57sahba9iJctOSgpDhBXucA20LfM6nBXA1sqYnQ==
```

Java

```
 val password = "password"
 val derivedKeyBytes = generateKey(password)?.encoded
 val base64Key = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(derivedKeyBytes)
 println("derivedKey $base64Key") //IC40btdTy83WnpQNWODFF8FO7eh8y8oLnncuKJBE29s=
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the posted result of the Kotlin code. Probably the passwords don't match, which can't be said exactly since you didn't post the password used in the Kotlin code. In the NodeJS code the key length has to be specified in byte (32) and not as in the Kotlin code in bit (256), hence the different lengths of the generated keys.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @Topaco, the issue was the key length fixed the kotlin code by multiplying 256 * 8. You can go ahead and add it as the answer so I can accept it